# How to remove the padding/space on the last item in slick carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

First I'm not using `centerMode: true`, instead, I used `slick-list` `padding-right of 20%`. My question is how can I remove the `padding-right` of the last item in slick carousel. I'm thinking about the use of checking the `length` of an item in slick then set it on `slickSetOption`, but I have no idea of how to do that.

Btw, you can change the code the important thing is I want to get rid of the space on the last item of the slick, but slick `infinite: false` and `centerMode: false` will stay.

Below is my code and to better understand here is the box code [https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/ExOOQoY).

```js
function slickRemoveLastSpaceItem() {
    $('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        infinite: false
    });
}

slickRemoveLastSpaceItem();
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.container {
  font-family:Arial;
  max-width:800px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.slider-content {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px !important;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.slick-list {
  padding: 0 20% 0 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider slider-for">
    <div class="slider-content">1</div>
    <div class="slider-content">2</div>
    <div class="slider-content">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to stop the carousel at the right edge of the last item, still showing 20% of the previous item? Or do you want to show the last item at full 100% width?

Comment: I want the last item to be a full width, without any padding or margin.

Answer (score 1):

You can `slick.slideCount` and change padding when the last item will become visible. In this case I used a class for it.

```js
function slickRemoveLastSpaceItem() {
    $('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        infinite: false
    });
}

slickRemoveLastSpaceItem();

$('.slider-for').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  if(nextSlide == slick.slideCount-1) {
    $('.slick-list').addClass('lastItem');
  } else {
    $('.slick-list').removeClass('lastItem');
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.container {
  font-family:Arial;
  max-width:800px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.slider-content {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px !important;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.slick-list {
  padding: 0 20% 0 0!important;
}

.slick-list.lastItem {
  padding: 0 0 0 20%!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider slider-for">
    <div class="slider-content">1</div>
    <div class="slider-content">2</div>
    <div class="slider-content">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want is the last item to be a full width, without any padding.

Comment: @clarkf, set the padding to 0

Comment: I did that but they have some delay on the script for the last item, you can check it here https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/ExOOQoY